# empty() and append() jquery, how does it work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a question, I have this script on my page:

```
$('div').html('<span class="test_class">Some text inside span</span>');

$('button').click(function() {      
    $('div').html('<span class="test_class">Now its personal</span>');
});

$('.test_class').click(function() {     
    console.log('test_class CLICKED');          
});
```

When the page loads and I click on my span - everything's perfect, I get a console.log() in web console, but after I click the button and click on my new span - I don't get a console.log(). Can you please tell me why? And how can i get it work? Thank you.

Comment: Post a complete code example please, including the relevant HTML. I don't see a button to the clicked on. Odds are this is just an example on event delegation and you need to use .on() instead of click().

Answer (score 3):

It's because the event-handler is bound to the `<span>` element, with:

```
$('.test_class').click(function() {     
    console.log('test_class CLICKED');          
});
```

And then you remove that `<span>` and create a new one (`.html()` works by writing over/replacing the existing HTML of the element, when used as a setter); which has no event-handler bound to it (because it wasn't present on the page at the time of document-ready).

To do what you seem to want, you'd need to use delegated event-handling:

```
$(document).on('click', '.test_class', function() {     
    console.log('test_class CLICKED');          
});
```

But, rather than `document`, you should use the closest element that's present on document-ready at the time of event-handling; which could be the parent `<div>`:

```
$('div').on('click', '.test_class', function() {     
    console.log('test_class CLICKED');          
});
```

But because of the non-specific selector, that will be bound to *all* `<div>` elements. Alternatively, you could use some traversing to do the same:

```
$('.test_class').closest('div').on('click', '.test_class', function () {
    console.log('test_class clicked');
});
```

But that becomes a little unwieldy and looks moderately ridiculous (but it will work, since the event-handling is still delegated to the `<div>` ancestor and then remains bound to that `<div>`).

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Hey, thanks! i rad half of your comment and already tested 'on' method and it worked. Tomorrow i will read the rest of the stuff and proceed with the jquery learning.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that the following Javascript gets executed only the first time you load the page:

```
 $('.test_class').click(function() {     
            console.log('test_class CLICKED');          
        });
```

So when the page loads, it finds the `span` with test_class style class and attaches the click event handler.

When you click on the text, the old `span` to which the event handler was attached is replaced. Even though the new `span` has style class of 'test_class', it does not have the even handler attached. To attach the event handler to this new span, you will have to execute the above Javascript again.

Here's a JS Fiddle which puts the JS in a function and calls it when the span is replaced: http://jsfiddle.net/zyzbxb7u/